# SQL query with COALESCE and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, coalesce

Sorry for bothering you, but I am stuck at sqlite queries :(

I have a table:

```
sport country place type
ski  swe 1 1
ski  nor 2 1
ski  rus 3 1
luge swe 1 1
luge usa 2 1
luge ger 3 1
bob  nor 1 1
bob  rus 2 1
bob  ger 3 1
```

where place is 1 for gold, 2 for silver, 3 for bronze

Now the normal displaying scenario is a list of countries, first max gold, then silver then bronze. For that example it would be:

```
swe g:2 s:0 b:0 sum:2
rus g:0 s:1 b:1 sum:2
usa g:0 s:1 b:0 sum:1
nor g:0 s:0 b:2 sum:2
```

to do that I am doing:

```
select
    country,
    sum(case when place = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as gold,
    sum(case when place = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as silver,
    sum(case when place = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as bronce,
    count(*) as allmedals
from 
    results 
group by 
    country 
order by 
    gold DESC, silver DESC, bronce DESC
```

That works so far. But I have another table "countries", full name, short name and some "type".

```
[name] [short]
usa      USA  
germany  GER  
russia   RUS  
norway   NOR  
poland   POL
```

I want to combine tables "results" and "countries", so that I have a list all of them from the table "countries", and if there is no results there, then its just a 0. so I tried:

```
SELECT 
    c.name as c_name,
    COALESCE(sum(case when r.place = 1 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as gold,
    COALESCE(sum(case when r.place = 2 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as silver,
    COALESCE(sum(case when r.place = 3 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as bronce
FROM 
    countries AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    results AS r ON c.short = r.country 
WHERE 
    r.type = 1 
GROUP BY 
    r.country
ORDER BY 
    gold DESC, silver DESC, bronce DESC, c.name DESC"
```

But the problem is, I see only a list of countries, that have a row in the table "results". I think its because of "r.type = 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN results as r ON c.short = r.country 
WHERE r.type = 1
```

to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN results as r ON c.short = r.country and r.type = 1
```

This works for me just fine

```
select 
c.name,
sum(case when place = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as gold,
sum(case when place = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as silver,
sum(case when place = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as bronce,
count(*) as allmedals
from countries  c 
left outer join results r on c.short = r.country
group by c.name
order by gold desc, silver desc, broncedesc, c.name desc
```

Comment: !!!!!! That is the solution !!!!!! Actually I did not know, taht it is allowed to do multiple operations within JOIN. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand what "No, it doesn't work!!! It shows only ONE row after rows with results!" means.

Comment: Sorry for unclear comment. For example I have 5 countries: swe, rus, usa, nor, slo in table "countries".. and only 2: swe and rus in "results". Then it shows 3 rows. swe, rus, and usa(first found by c.name DESC).

Comment: "group by "  was a problem, by my it was "group by r.country"

Comment: @user1908375 ah I see.  do you understand why that was a problem?  you were grouping by data in the results table, your outer join, where all of the data for country, for the rows that don't exist in that table are null. Hence the single row.  Sorry I should have been able to pick that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     c.name,
     SUM(CASE WHEN place = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gold,
     sum(CASE WHEN place = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS silver,
     sum(CASE WHEN place = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bronce,
     IFNULL (COUNT(r.country), 0) AS allmedals
FROM countries  c 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN records AS r ON c.short = r.country 
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name asc;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".